# NHibernate + ViewModel +MVC + Optimistic lock

Tags: nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-2, locking, viewmodel

Ok we have the following senario, but how do you do [Optimistic Locking](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/optimisticOfflineLock.html)

we have a Customer Class

- Name
- Address
- Version

The version is a collision varible (int) which when the row is edited the version will increase by 1.

Now we have Martin who open Customer 129, as with a view model the model object is flattened into the View Model then passed onto a Customer Edit Screen.

David in the mean time also opens the Customer 129 for edit, changes the name and saves.

Martin, who was still editing the customer (now an old version), goes to save his changes, at this point I would hope to see an Lock error to be thrown

the Question is how do you handle Optimistic locking with NH (using FluentNHibernate for mappings), would you do

- have to push the verion number into the ViewModel? then when it has been submitted with an update, load in the current Model object and check the version Numbers
- Or is threre a better way (I know NH would do versioning if I Load, Edit and Update in the same session)

one extra thing, this scenario will be used on a farm, not sharing a cache

many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is essentially an offline lock, which NHibernate doesn't deal with.

What you need to do is something like:

Edit Request:

- Load entity
- Push entity into ViewModel (including Version Number)
- etc...

Save Request:

- Load entity (again)
- Check Version Number from view model against entity

  - if not the same show error/reconciliation options
  - else update entity, etc...

Comment: that confirms my thoughts, (did not think a lock may be required but its a good point) http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#transactions-optimistic-manual